# Construct a linear transformation $T:\Bbb R^4 →\Bbb R^4$ such that $\ker T =\operatorname{im}T =\operatorname{span}\{(1,1,1,1) , (0,1,1,1)\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I need help for the following exercise:

> Construct a linear transformation $T:\Bbb R^4 →\Bbb R^4$ such that $$\ker T =\operatorname{im}T =\operatorname{span}\{(1,1,1,1) , (0,1,1,1)\}.$$

I know that $$T(1,1,1,1)=T(0,1,1,1)=\vec 0$$ and I completed these two vectors to a basis of $\Bbb R^4$, so I took $$T(0,0,0,1)=(0,0,0,1)\quad\text{and}\quad T(0,1,0,0) = (1,1,1,1),$$ but I couldn't find a formula for $T(x,y,z,w)$.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I know that T(1,1,1,1)=T(0,1,1,1)=0 and copmleted these two vectors to R^4 bases so I took T(0,0,01)=(0,0,0,1) and T(0,1,0,0) = (1,1,1,1) but I couldn't find a formal T(x,y,z,w)

Comment: No worries. Please learn to [format your formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4880241/revisions). And delete your comments when you think they have become useless.

Answer (score 2):

Your (implicit) claim that $$e_1:=(1,1,1,1),\quad e_2:=(0,1,1,1),\quad e_3:=(0,0,0,1),\quad e_4:=(0,1,0,0)$$ make a basis of $\Bbb R^4$ is correct (how would you prove it?), hence for any choice of four vectors $f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4\in\Bbb R^4$, there is a unique linear transformation $T:\Bbb R^4\to\Bbb R^4$ that maps $e_i$ to $f_i$ for $i=1,2,3,4$. (So, you won't need any `formula $T(x,y,z,w)$'.)

- In order to get $\ker T=V:=\operatorname{span}\{e_1,e_2\}$, you are right that $f_1=f_2=\vec0$ is necessary (but not sufficient on its own, since $\ker T$ might still be larger).
- In order to get moreover $\operatorname{im}T=V$, a necessary condition is
  $\operatorname{span}\{f_3,f_4\}=V$ (but not sufficient on its own, since $\operatorname{im}T$ might be larger, depending on the choice of $f_1,f_2$).

Your choice $f_3=e_3$ is therefore not convenient, since $e_3=(0,0,0,1)\notin\{(x,y,y,y)\mid x,y\in\Bbb R\}=V$. If you replace it for instance with $f_3=e_2$ (keeping your $f_4=e_1$ and $f_1=f_2=\vec0$), then you are done:
$$\ker T\supseteq V,\quad\operatorname{im}T\supseteq V$$
hence (by the [rank nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem)) these inclusions are actually equalities.